# Imagestream in openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

What is the concept of imagestream in.openshift 
How is it connected to a docker image ..
I am trying to deploy an angular project into minishift
But i cant quite understand what is a image stream

Comment: `ImageStream` is a collection of container images. These container images are abstracted as `ImageStreamTag`. On the other words, `ImageStream` is composed of one or many `ImageStreamTag`, each maps to a container image.

Comment: https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/core_concepts/builds_and_image_streams.html#image-streams

Comment: if i deploy a nodejs image , what does it mean?

Comment: It will create an `imagestream`, which contains one `imagestreamtag`, which points to this nodejs image.

Comment: Updates of this `imagestreamtag` will trigger a new deployment. Which means, if you bind this `imagestreamtag` to another image (a new version of your nodejs application), OpenShift will redeploy this application with the new image.

Comment: Additionally to what has been mentioned above, you may want to have a look on [this older blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/image-streams-faq/) (similar info to the docs linked by Will, structured in a format of a blog article) and [these interactive learning scenarios](https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/) (esp. the [Deploying Applications from Images](https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/deploying-images/), but others are good too).